# Task's 'next run time' and 'last run time' don't agree with the interval in Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, python, task-scheduler

I am automating the running of a python script in Windows 10.
Rather than having a daemon periodically running the script, I opted to use the Task Scheduler, which allows for the easy running of a script with administrator privileges.
I am updating the running interval of the task programmatically based on the output of the script.

The problem is that while the interval seems to change in Task Scheduler, the time between 'next run time' and 'last run time' is considerably shorter than the interval.

Am I doing something wrong?

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QNVd.png)

Here is the line in the script that sets the interval:
`subprocess.run('schtasks /Change /TN <task path> /RI {} 
                 /RU <username> /RP <password>'.format(next_interval))`

The script writes a log file, and the interval there corresponds to the interval in the Task Scheduler.

Changing the interval manually doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem, as I can see, has been resolved. Maybe it was the manual changing of the interval that did it, I am not sure.

To try to fix this yourself, try these:

- Reboot your device
- Look through your code
- Change the interval manually
- Delete the task and make a new one

Best of luck!

Update: The problem hasn't been fixed, but changing the way the task is created may help someone; try creating the task using the command prompt. In the end, I settled for a constant 5-minute interval.